# Declaring events in polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have the following element declared in polymer

```
<polymer-element name="Map-List-Element" attributes="mapName recordId">
    <template>
        <style>
            :host {
                display: block;
                position: relative;
                background-color:#fff;
                padding: 20px;
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-size:14px;
                font-weight:400;
                margin-bottom:10px;
                border: 1px solid #ddd;

            }
            core-label {
                margin-bottom:20px;
                display:block;
            }
            core-icon {
                color:#A0A0A0;
                margin-right:10px;
                cursor:pointer;
            }
        </style>
        <core-label>{{mapName}}</core-label>
        <span flex></span>
        <core-icon-button icon="av:play-arrow"></core-icon-button>
        <core-icon icon="settings" on-tap="{{settingsClicked}}"></core-icon>
        <core-icon icon="delete"></core-icon>
        <content/>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            mapName: "",
            recordId: 0,
            settingsClicked: function (event, detail, sender) {
                this.fire('show-Settings', { recordId: this.recordId, mapName: this.name });
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

That in turn is called by the following custom element

```
<link rel="import" href="elements.html" />
<link rel="import" href="Map-List-Element.html" />
<polymer-element name="Map-List">
    <template>
        <template repeat="{{m in response.data}}">
            <map-list-element mapname="{{m.mapName}}" recordid="{{m.Id}}" on-show-settings="{{showSettings}}">
            </map-list-element> 
        </template>
        <core-ajax id="ajax"
                   auto=true
                   method="POST"
                   url="/RoutingMapHandler.php?Command=retrieve&Id=all"
                   response="{{response}}"
                   handleas="json"
                   on-core-error="{{handleError}}" 
                   on-core-response="{{handleResponse}}">
        </core-ajax>

    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('Map-List', {
            created: function () {
            },

            handleError: function (event, detail, sender) {
            },

            handleResponse: function (event,detail,sender) {
            },
            showSettings: function (event, detail, sender) {
                alert('Fired showSettings');
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

When I click on the core-icon with the settings icon it calls the 'settingsClicked' function. The 'event handler' in the Map-List element which contains another alert is not called - the alert in 'showSettings' is not shown.

So given the events declared in the Map-Element element, how do you create the event handler in the Map-List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event handler declaration is correct (`on-show-settings="{{showSettings}}"` and the corresponding function).

But you got a typo in the `fire` statement .The event name must be all lowercase. So replace `this.fire('show-Settings'` with `this.fire('show-settings'` and your code will work.